# How to load a JSON file to a single column of a Redshift table

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load the below JSON sample to a single column in Redshift table from S3 as a Proof of Concept. However it is not working successfully. Any help on the same would be of great help.

(This is just a sample JSON with random values to check if it is working)

```json
{
    "Name":"ABC",
    "Department":"HR",
    "Rollno":1,
    "Salary":1000,
    "RS Factor":4,
    "Expected Value":8.1,
    "Comment": "", 
    "Correction Factor": 1,
    "Fruit":"Apple",
    "Size":"Large",
    "Color":"Red"
}
```

COPY command used:

```sql
COPY "schema"."table" ("column") FROM 's3://bucketname/file.json' 
WITH CREDENTIALS AS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXX' 
MAXERROR AS 0 DATEFORMAT AS 'auto' TIMEFORMAT AS 'auto' 
ACCEPTANYDATE TRIMBLANKS 
EMPTYASNULL 
BLANKSASNULL 
COMPUPDATE OFF 
STATUPDATE OFF ROUNDEC 
JSON AS 'auto' 
ENCODING AS UTF8 ACCEPTINVCHARS AS '?' 
IGNOREHEADER AS 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to a single column"? Do you want the field to contain the complete JSON blob as displayed? Can you please show us an example of the output you are expecting? Normally, it is better to load the JSON attributes into separate columns so that they can be easily queried by Redshift. While Redshift does contain some functions for parsing JSON fields, the tables will not be optimized for querying.

Comment: The final result that we are targeting is the entire JSON structure to be inserted to a single column  the reason being JSON fields are dynamic in nature. Is it possible or do we need to go with a schema less DB like mongo or dynamo

Comment: Regardless of whether it is possible, loading data in this format is not a good idea for Amazon Redshift. The true power of Amazon Redshift comes from distributing data across nodes (Distribution Key) and sorting data so that `WHERE` statements are highly efficient (Sort Key). If you wish to store data as a JSON blob, it will not take advantage of any of the benefits that Redshift can offer. If this is your main/only data you wish to store in Redshift, then you should either store it in true row/column format, or use a different type of database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `json 'noshred'` instead of `auto` . Thats all . it will load the json to single column without breaking it into multiple column

```
COPY "schema"."table" ("column") FROM 's3://bucketname/file.json' 
WITH CREDENTIALS AS 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXX' 
MAXERROR AS 0 DATEFORMAT AS 'auto' TIMEFORMAT AS 'auto' 
ACCEPTANYDATE TRIMBLANKS 
EMPTYASNULL 
BLANKSASNULL 
COMPUPDATE OFF 
STATUPDATE OFF ROUNDEC 
JSON 'noshred'
ENCODING AS UTF8 ACCEPTINVCHARS AS '?' 
IGNOREHEADER AS 0
```